# Kettle - Load Balancing

Tags: performance, load-balancing, pentaho, etl, kettle

Is there any way to handle **load balancing** in **Pentaho ETL Servers**? PDI should be able to handle switching of the servers once the memory increases more than the set target to a new server without having to fail or restart the job. *A feature quite similar to Informatica powercenter.*

I know we can cluster the data in PDI and also load balancing of server are usually done in the server side. Is it possible to do the same from a PDI point of view?

*[Note: Apologies if you think this question is broad.]*

Comment: check out this answer https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2016/10/16/load-balancing-across-slaves-in-pentaho-data-integration/

Answer (score 0):

I found a document in their enterprise edition support saying,

> As of now dynamic load balancing and fail over features are not
>   supported with PDI server.

But I think you can do jobs & transformation level clustering.
I found several URLs which might help you.

[creating-clustered-transformations](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.in/2013/03/creating-clustered-transformation-in.html)

[partitioning-data-on-clustered-pentaho](http://diethardsteiner.blogspot.in/2013/03/partitioning-data-on-clustered-pentaho.html)

[clustering-in-kettle](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2011/10/clustering-in-kettle/)

[How to build a simple PDI cluster](http://open-bi.blogspot.in/2009/11/hi-all-i-would-like-to-start-serie-of.html)

[Create Carte Clusters](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0P0/0U0/050)

And also alternatively you can have dynamic load balancing and fail over feature on the database server side rather than on PDI server.

Comment: Sorry @Marlon i was not looking for this answer. I know how to build in cluster in PDI and scale the data across. Rather i would like to know how to handle high availability and load balancing of jobs and data.